# jQuery datatable retain filter parameter after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working with a datatable, as per some of my previous questions. I was able to add INPUT fields at the top of the table that conducts individual column searches in the datatable.

What I need to do now is retain the parameter entered in the INPUT field (or fields) after the page refreshes.

Here is my code so far:

```
 // header input filters
 $('#example1 .filters th').each(function(){
   var title = $('#example1 thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
   $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />');
 });

 // set and print the datatable
 var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
   "ajax": 'api/dateset.php',
   "iDisplayLength": 25,
   "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
   "scrollY": 580,
   "scrollX": true,
   "bDestroy": true,
   "stateSave": true
 });

 // Apply the search to columns
 $dataTable.columns().eq(0).each(function(colIdx){
   $('input', $('.filters th')[colIdx]).on('keyup change', function(){
     $dataTable
       .column(colIdx)
       .search(this.value)
       .draw();
   });
 });
```

If you'll notice in the portion above where I set the $dataTable, you should see "stateSave": true .  Using that, when the page refreshes, it does save the parameter search entered by the user, but it doesn't display the text in the INPUT field.

That is where I am stuck.

Here is a visual representation:

Before refresh -

[image]

After refresh -

[image]

As you see in the second picture, the search is good for BOOKING beginning with TEST222, but the text is no longer visible in the BOOKING INPUT field.

I did come across this post:  https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback

But I am not sure how to implement that code into my code.  I am not even sure if stateSaveCallback is the right function to use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found this post:  http://live.datatables.net/neqozaj/1/edit

Utilizing that post, I was able to add this piece of code to the overall function:

```
 var state = $dataTable.state.loaded();
 if ( state ) {
   $dataTable.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
   var colSearch = state.columns[colIdx].search;

   if ( colSearch.search ) {
     $('input', $('.filters th')[colIdx]).val( colSearch.search );
   }
  });
  $dataTable.draw();
 }
```

Using this, I was able to to achieve the effect I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If you have column level filter then try the below code.

```
// Restore state, search and column level filter
    var state = table.state.loaded();
    if (state) {
        table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
            var colSearch = state.columns[colIdx].search;

            if (colSearch.search) {
                $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).val(colSearch.search);
            }
        });

        table.draw();
    }


    // Apply the search
    table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
        $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column(colIdx)
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        });
    });
```