# Datatables Individual search columns

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have table which has data tables individual column search functionality and the table is loaded when form submit button is clicked.
Now when i search on those individual column I get the data filtered data in my table. But when I resubmit the form without reloading the page the filters are also gone.
before resubmit:

[image]

after resubmit:

[image]

I want the filters remain as the same after resubmit as those were before resubmit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  
    $('#example tfoot th').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    });
 
    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api()
                .columns()
                .every(function () {
                    var that = this;
 
                    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function () {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                            that.search(this.value).draw();
                        }
                    });
                });
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at the DataTables [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option - see if that meets your needs. "_When this initialisation option is active and the end user reloads the page the table's state will be altered to match what they had previously set up._"

Comment: thanks mate using stateSave it worked perfectly . @andrewJames

Comment: Solution for the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030451/jquery-datatable-retain-filter-parameter-after-refresh